# Trigger a piece of code on button click in php

Tags: javascript, php

Basically what I'm trying to do is to execute a piece of code or a function once a button in clicked. I don't have any html form that sends the request and I don't want the page to reload.

Example:
If I click the button named Hello I want to execute the next piece of code in php

`echo 'Welcome '.$user.' !';`

Later edit:
I didn't said that i don't want to use AJAX, and YES, I know that PHP is serverside.

Comment: So, you know what is php and how it is executed, right?

Comment: PHP is serverside code and javascript/jquery is client side code. Unless you use ajax, you cant do this

Comment: learn the difference in server side scripting and client side scripting

Comment: I didn't said that i don't want to use AJAX, and YES, i know that PHP is serverside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use AJAX or reload the page/frame with the new info from user. 
Take this example and try to modify to your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between both languages. **PHP** is run on the server, which means that when you retrieve a page, you send a request, the server will handle that request and give you the page back.

At that moment, the PHP part of this story has ended and the client-side part starts. When you click a button, and you want something to happen, you will probably use **JavaScript**. This language runs in your browser.

To make the two communicate with each other, you have to make a request somehow to the server from your JavaScript code, either by:

- submitting a form,
- reloading a page,
- an AJAX request.

Since the first two options are not wanted by you, so I'll explain you how you can use the third one, the AJAX request.

The AJAX request is actually an asynchronous request to the server, you don't need to reload your page, it runs all behind the screens. To do this, you will need to connect your event handler to that AJAX request, for example by doing the same as in the next code example. This is written using the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) because it simplifies event handling and sending AJAX requests. If you don't believe me or you don't want to use it, you can always look at [Filipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803291/1915448), which gives you a proper example of how to handle AJAX requests without jQuery.

```js
$("#myButton").on("click", function() {
    $.get("theOtherPage.php", function(data) {
        // Do something with "data"
    });
});
```

In this case, an `onClick` event hanlder is added to a button `#myButton` and when it's clicked, a page called `theOtherPage.php` is requested. Here you put the content you want, for example:

```php
echo 'Welcome '.$user.' !';
```

When the request is completed, the data will be available in the `data` argument of the callback. You can do something with it now (show it to the user for example).